# Swi-prolog, need help defining my conditions

Tags: prolog

So I have a project, and I'm trying to create a predicate which has 3 different cases, which I will explain.

```
swapandp(L, P, Content, L) :-
    refP(L, P, Content), !.
```

This is the first case where `refP` gives me the content of the list L on the position P, and if the content is equal to Content, it returns true and stops right there, because if the content is the same, I don't need to change anything in L.

```
swapandp(L, P, [Content], NewL) :-
    swap(L, P, Content, NewL1),
    relatedPs(P, Ps),
    delNum(Content, NewL1, Ps, NewL).
```

This is the second case where, if Content is a one-element list, then it puts Content in the P position of the list L, and then uses a predicate i created to delete the same content in the positions related to P, which are put into a list Ps by another predicate relatedPs.

```
swapandp(L, P, Content, NewL) :-
    swap(L, P,  Content, NewL).
```

This is the third case where if Content is a list with more then 1 element, then it just puts Content into the position P of the list L.

but something is wrong. Because I'm probably not defining the 3 cases correctly, sorry for my english and thanks for helping.

EDIT 1:
Been trying out some things and now the first and third case are working so my problem is not the 2nd one.

I tried this:
?- swapandp([[[1,2], [1,2], [3], [1,4,5], [1,4]]], (1,1), [1], NewL).
NewL = [[[1], [1, 2], [3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4]]].

but the expected result should be:
NewL = [[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [4]]].

cant figure it out.

EDIT 2:

```
refP(L, (Plin, Pcol), Content) :-
    nth1(Plin,L,Line),
    nth1(Pcol,Line,Content).

applyActionToL(L,_,[],L) :- !.
applyActionToL(Puz,Action,[P | R],N_Puz) :-
    Action =.. Lst_Action,
    append(Lst_Action, [L,P,Res],Actionwithargs),
    Lit =.. Actionwithargs,
    call(Lit),
    applyActionToL(Res,Action,R,NewL).
```

But applyActionToL and refP were defined by my teacher so, i guess its working.

```
delNumAux(N, L, P, NewL) :-
    refP(Puz, Pos, Content),
    subtract(Content, Num, Content1),
    swapandp(L, P,  Content1, NewL).

delNum(N, L, Ps, NewL) :-
    applyActionToL(L, delNumAux(Num), Ps, NewL).
```

Edit 3:

I ended up being able to fix it myself! Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: Can you provide a complete runnable definition?

Comment: sure, will edit and add it.

Answer (score 0):

a wild guess:

```
swapandpropagate(L, P, [Content], OutL) :-
    swap(L, P, Content, NewL),
    relatedPs(P, Ps),
    delNum(Content, NewL, Ps, OutL).
```